# Запуск программ в virtualenv из внешней среды

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv

Каким образом можно запускать программы, которые находятся в virtualenv, из внешней среды? Написать скрипт? Или с помощью virtualenvwrapper?
Например, у меня на машине не установлена programname, но она установлена в virtualenv. Я не заходя в virtual набираю в консоли programname и она выполняется.

Answer (score 1):

При запуске необходимо указывать путь к интерпритатору в виртуальном окружении
    `/path_to_virtual/bin/python you_script.py`

Аналогично `python script.py` где путь к интерпретатору `python` уже есть в Вашем стандартном окружении и переменной PATH